# How to completely cover a header with a background image?

Tags: html, css

How do I remove the white space between my header and the top of the page and between my header and my menu. + How do I make my background picture of the header fully visible? Due to my studies I can't work with "div" tags.
**Here is my html code:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Startpagina</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/algemeen.css">
</head>
<body>

<header class="hoofdfoto">
    <h1>MoveIt</h1>
</header>

<nav>
    <ul id="menu">
        <li><a href="html/aanvraag_offerte.html"><img src="images/offerte.png" alt="Aanvraag offerte"></a></li>
        <li><a href="html/verhuur.html"><img src="images/verhuur.png" alt="Verhuur"></a></li>
        <li><a href="html/stappenplan_verhuis.html"><img src="images/stappenplan.png" alt="Stappenplan Verhuis"></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="html/geschiedenis.html"><img src="images/geschiedenis.png" alt="Geschiedenis"></a></li>
        <li><a href="html/contact.html"><img src="images/contact.png" alt="Contact"></a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>

</body>
</html>
```

**here is my css code:**

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    background-color: slategray;

}

h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 50px;
}

.hoofdfoto {
    background: url("../images/header.jpg") center no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

#menu {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: gray;
    width: 100%;
}
#menu li{
    display: inline;

}
#menu li:hover{
    background-color: darkgray;
}
#menu li a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
#menu li a img{
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    padding: 0 8%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove your `h1` tag `margin`

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    background-color: slategray;

}

h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 50px;
    margin:0px;      /*Add this in your css*/
}

.hoofdfoto {
    background: url("https://imagejournal.org/wp-content/uploads/bb-plugin/cache/23466317216_b99485ba14_o-panorama.jpg") center no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

#menu {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: gray;
    width: 100%;
}
#menu li{
    display: inline;

}
#menu li:hover{
    background-color: darkgray;
}
#menu li a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
#menu li a img{
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    padding: 0 8%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Startpagina</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/algemeen.css">
</head>
<body>

<header class="hoofdfoto">
    <h1>MoveIt</h1>
</header>

<nav>
    <ul id="menu">
        <li><a href="html/aanvraag_offerte.html"><img src="images/offerte.png" alt="Aanvraag offerte"></a></li>
        <li><a href="html/verhuur.html"><img src="images/verhuur.png" alt="Verhuur"></a></li>
        <li><a href="html/stappenplan_verhuis.html"><img src="images/stappenplan.png" alt="Stappenplan Verhuis"></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="html/geschiedenis.html"><img src="images/geschiedenis.png" alt="Geschiedenis"></a></li>
        <li><a href="html/contact.html"><img src="images/contact.png" alt="Contact"></a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>

</body>
</html>
```